# How to locate and click on the play button in spotify using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, spotify

I have been trying to make selenium play a specific song from a specific link but when done so on a new account, it just doesn't want to interact and gives me the:

```
could not locate the element
```

exception even though its visible, rendered (I can click on it manually) and I used different methods like xpath and class name (I'm stuck with css selector because it worked enough for me to this point). Here's the snippet of a part from this script since anything before it was just logging in, all of the modules I imported and some credentials I want to keep private like my emails and stuff:

```
driver.get('https://open.spotify.com/track/0WSEq9Ko4kFPt8yo3ICd6T?si=e2c993506d17435b&nd=1')
time.sleep(3)
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('PFgcCoJSWC3KjhZxHDYH').click
```

Answer (score 0):

This will locate the element for you:

```
playbutton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@data-testid="play-button"]')
```

It's not pure selenium, but something like this should work for the click:

```
playbutton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@data-testid="play-button"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", playbutton)
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the **Play** button on the [**Spotify**](https://open.spotify.com/track/0WSEq9Ko4kFPt8yo3ICd6T?si=e2c993506d17435b&nd=1) page, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://open.spotify.com/track/0WSEq9Ko4kFPt8yo3ICd6T?si=e2c993506d17435b&nd=1')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#onetrust-close-btn-container button[aria-label='Close']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-testid='action-bar-row'] button[data-testid='play-button'][aria-label='Play']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://open.spotify.com/track/0WSEq9Ko4kFPt8yo3ICd6T?si=e2c993506d17435b&nd=1')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='onetrust-close-btn-container']//button[@aria-label='Close']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='action-bar-row']//button[@data-testid='play-button' and @aria-label='Play']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score -2):

try this class name: `Button-qlcn5g-0 kgFBvD`.

Or you can just copy xpath and use find_element_by_xpath()

Comment: Both dont work.

Comment: @Drum right click the button tag element and copt the full xpath, it will be a long path, that should work.